# R: How do I concisely assign names to vector parameter components?

Tags: r, function

I would to define a function in R along the following lines:

```
testfunction <- function(vector){

adam <- vector[1]

becky <- vector[2]

charlie <- vector[3]

david <- vector[4]

...

return( adam + becky^2 -2*charlie*david +...)

}
```

I could define the function purely in terms of "vector[1], vector[2]" etc, but I'd like to keep it in terms of "adam, becky" etc. The problem is my input vector parameter is very large and I have to define multiple functions like this. I'd like to be able to do something like define a vector

```
names <- c(adam,becky,charlie,...)
```

and then put

```
names <- vector
```

in the definition of each function, but of course this doesn't work. Does anyone have any good suggestions for how to assign names to the input vector components in a concise manner that can be used many times?

**Follow-up (10/9/2014):**

I actually need the result of this function to survive, so I may need the .Global environment; I'm not sure. I want to separate the name assignment part of the function from the rest of it (because it's actually quite long - I've edited it here - and I'd like to insert it into multiple functions as a subroutine). What I want to write is along these lines:

```
function1 <- function(vector, names){

for (i in 1:length(vector){

  assign(names[i], vector[,i], envir = environment())
}

}

function2 <- function(vector){

 function1(vector,names1)

 return( adam + becky^2 - 2*charlie*david +...)

 }
```

The problem is that the assignment doesn't survive outside of the environment of function1, so function2 doesn't recognise "adam" etc when I try to call those names. How do I adjust the environment to take care of that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
v1 <- 1:4
names1 <- c("adam", "becky", "charlie", "david")

testfunction <- function(vect, names){
for(i in seq_along(names)){
assign(names[i], vect[i], envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
return(adam + becky^2 -2*charlie*david)
}

testfunction(v1, names1)
#[1] -19
```

#### Update

By changing `.GlobalEnv` to `environment()`, you can do the `assign` locally

```
testfunction <- function(vect, names){ 
for(i in seq_along(names1)){
assign(names1[i], vect[i],environment())
}
return(adam + becky^2 - 2*charlie*david)
}

testfunction(v1, names1)
#[1] -19
adam
#Error: object 'adam' not found
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the answer a colleague provided literally as I hit "submit"!

Comment: This creates a site effect for the function which is undesirable in functional programming.

Comment: @LIPD This creates global variables that are not removed once the function is evaluated. Also, if you happen to have a variable `adam` in the global environment it will be overwritten. All variables created by a function should be local to the function's environment.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've actually edited my original question to ask a follow-up which addresses the environment question.

Comment: @LIPD It might be better to post as a new question so that more people would look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps with the help of `do.call`:

```
testfunction <- function(adam, becky, charlie, david) {
  ...
}

do.call(testfunction, as.list(vector))
```

The distribution of vector values to the parameters happens in `do.call`.

Roland's disclaimer applies here, too -- it's a rather brittle approach. Why don't you use named vectors or lists in the first place?

Comment: Thanks. All good answers. Very much an R newbie, so I wasn't familiar with a lot of these functions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend it, but you can do something like this:

```
testfunction <- function(vector){
  names(vector) <-  c("adam", "becky", "charlie", "david")
  list2env(as.list(vector), envir = environment())

  adam + becky^2 -2*charlie*david 
}
testfunction(1:4)
#[1] -19
```

If it breaks you get to keep the pieces.