# How do I get a function to retain values I assign? (R)

Tags: r, function, environment-variables

This is a follow-up to this question I posted earlier about how to assign values to a vector of names: [R: How do I concisely assign names to vector parameter components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25567130/r-how-do-i-concisely-assign-names-to-vector-parameter-components/25567336?noredirect=1#comment40295483_25567336)

I want to assign values to a vector of names and I need to do this in multiple different functions of the form function2 in the code below. Rather than insert the code into every function, I'd like to write a subroutine of the form function1 below, and call that in each function. Unfortunately, the name assignments are kept within function1 when I call it and don't survive to be used within the "return( adam +...)" part. I suspect this is something to do with how I specify the environment for the assign function, but I don't know how to fix it (I don't want to assign the names globally). Can anyone help?

The rough code I'm trying to use is below:

```
function1 <- function(vector, names){

for (i in 1:length(vector){

  assign(names[i], vector[,i], envir = environment())
}

}

function2 <- function(vector){

 names1 <- c("adam", "becky", "charlie",...)

 function1(vector,names1)

 return( adam + becky^2 - 2*charlie*david +...)

 }
```

Comment: I would avoid to use `assign` and global variable/environment headeach. Use instead a "named vector"/list where you set all you variables.

Comment: You need to study the concepts of functional programming and R in particular. You are making these things much more difficult for yourself than they need to be.

Comment: +1 Roland. Read this, which is basically The Manual for R http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read of that. In the mean time, any suggestions for this bit of code?

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to write a function for name assignment, let alone one that contains a loop.

Use a named vector instead.
For example:

```
vec1 <- c("this","that","the other")
vec2 <- c(5,7,9)
names(vec2) <- vec1
```

then this works

```
vec2['that'] <- vec2['that'] + 1
print(vec2)
 this      that the other 
    5         8         9
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to do is not name the entries, but actually give those names the values. So in my example above, I want "adam" to have the value vector[1].

Comment: Thats possible to do, but unless you're specifically doing this for code-golf or illustrative reasons, that is an inferior implementation for readability, speed, and flexibility. Mostly the problem is that it disables you from doing any sort of group operation on all the variables without listing them individually by name, which defeats the point of making functions; if you know exactly what you want to do with each name (because you're making them constants), you don't need functions. Just list every name in the global scope and put the value you want in it.

Comment: ...and if there are too many "constant" variables to do that, then it's not what you want to do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
function1 <- function(vector, names, envir){
for (i in 1:length(vector)){
 assign(names[i], vector[i], envir = envir)
 }
 }

function2 <- function(vector){
names1 <- c("adam", "becky", "charlie", "david")
function1(vector,names1, envir=environment())
return(adam + becky^2 - 2*charlie*david)
}


v1 <- 1:4
function2(v1)
#[1] -19
adam
#Error: object 'adam' not found
```